# Orientation of a basis and of a vector

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, differential-geometry, analytic-geometry, topological-groups

Let $\mathbb{R}^n$ be the Euclidean space of dimension $n.$

We say that two ordered bases have the same orientation whenever the change-of-base matrix has determinant $>0.$

This determines an equivalence relation. Moreover, we say that the standard basis is positively oriented, so that any base equivalent to the standard basis under this relation is positively oriented.

> I would like to understand what does this mean geometrically. A
> change-of-base matrix is a symmetry $g\in
>  \text{Aut}(\mathbb{R}^n)=\text{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ and we define two
> ordered bases to be oriented in the same way whenever the unique
> symmetry realizing the change of base belongs of the subgroup of
> $\text{GL}^+(n,\mathbb{R})$ of $\text{Det}>0$ matrices. What is the
> geometric interpretation of this group?
>
> Is there such a thing as an orientation of a single vector, so that
> two bases are oriented in the same way if and only if the change of
> base symmetry does not change the orientation?

> Or maybe the choice of
> a basis prescribes the same orientation to all vectors? That is, expressing a vector with respect to a positive base means choosing a positive orientation of the vector? So that once a basis is chosen, all vectors are oriented in the same way?

Comment: This has to do with chirality; you can never rotate an image of your left hand to get an image of your right hand, so their difference is more than just a rotation. It requires a reflection. In dimension 2, a change-of-basis matrix that has positive determinant can always be seen as a rotation, scaling, and another rotation. Matrices with negative determinant always create a "reflection". In dimension 3 a similar result holds. In higher dimensions we just extend the idea from dimensions 2 and 3.

Comment: @abhi01nat by reflection you mean something with determinant $-1$ ? For example, why consider only reflections then and not just any involution? For example in dim $2$, why the simmetry $u \mapsto -u $, which has determinant $1$ doesn’t change the orientation of the base? I mean why we don’t want the definition to include this case for example

Comment: No, a single vector does not have an orientation. An *ordered* set of vectors has. If you swap two vectors, the orientation changes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_(vector_space)

Comment: Another way to look at this is the following: two ordered bases $b_1,\dots,b_n$ and $b'_1,\dots,b'_n$ have the same orientation if there is a family of invertible linear transformations $A_t, 0 \leq t \leq 1$, continuous with respect to $t$, such that $A_0$ is the identity and $A_1$ maps $b_i$ to $b'_i$ for $i = 1,\dots,n$. Thus, bases with the same orientation can be moved into each other continuously through non-degenerate transformations of the whole space, while to move between bases with different orientation, you need a discontinuous "jump" (a "reflection").

Comment: Your example taking a vector to its negative is the composition of two reflections. I encourage you to really try this with a picture of your left hand; its "negative" can be rotated to get back the original. This is why this is not considered a different orientation. @Daniel's comment is also instructive: two bases have the same orientation if the solids they span are homotopic to each other in the given vector space, where the homotopy is only allowed to pass through non-degenerate solids.

Comment: @DánielG. I like this point of view! Is it an "if and only if"?

Comment: @abhi01nat yes this thing about reflections is nice. Indeed I was hoping that the group of matrices with determinant $>0$ had some interpretation as a group of transformations of the space.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I already looked at the wikipedia page before asking the question. What I was wondering is: if we fix a base, for example the standard base, does it make sense to say that two given vectors have different orientation iff there is a reflection $r$ such that $rx=y$? Or maybe better, I was wondering if there was some definition of orientation in terms of the group of symmetries with positive determinant.

Comment: Reflecting a vector changes the sign of the determinant.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't know what you are talking about. A reflection is linear map with determinant $-1.$ I don't know what sign you are talking about.